# Tools to diff two Keynote '09 slideshows

Tags: keynote, productivity

Is there any tool which I can use to effectively diff two Keynote '09 slideshows?

**TL;DR**

An Apple Keynote (i.e. a .key) file consists of a directory structure which contains all the resources used in a slideshow (i.e. images, videos) and a `.apxl` file containing the structure and the text of the slideshow, encoded in a given format. Therefore, it should be possible to diff two versions of the same slideshow comparing the list of resources and the XML file. The comparison should give decent information about what has been changed or added between two versions of the same slideshow.

Is there any tool which is able to do some *clever* (e.g. strip metadata away from the comparison) *diffing* between two Keynote slideshows?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I ended up writing my own script who does that. It's available at:

https://github.com/robertoaloi/keynote-to-text

Contributions are welcome.

Comment: dead link... looks like you have a new account.
https://github.com/robertoaloi/keynote-to-text

Comment: Thanks. I have changed GitHub username recently. Updated.

Answer (score 0):

[DeltaWalker](http://www.deltopia.com/compare-merge-sync/macosx/) ($39,95) can compare many files and folders, including Keynote documents. But don't expect it to be an eye-catcher and check on graphic elements...

I compared two Keynote presentations and it looks like the software is only comparing the text.
I had some images in the files, but it doesn't check on that (unfortunately).

[image]

Answer (score 0):

[Bit Lasso Reveal](http://www.bitlasso.com/) is a commercial tool I wrote for finding and comparing slides; works with PowerPoint and Keynote.